# how to prevent showing patse icon after right click in ckeditor4

Tags: angular, ckeditor4

when I'm trying to right click into CKEditor its showing paste icon which is not working I have to avoid that icon showing after right click

am expecting after right click that icon should not be display

Answer (score 0):

Use [removeMenuIten( name )](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-removeMenuItem)

```
editor1.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    this.removeMenuItem('paste');
});
```